# Netsuite: How to debug workflow action script

Tags: debugging, workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I'm new on suitescript(Javascript based used in Netsuite custumization).
I have a workflow action script and  want to debug it via Scritp Debugger in Netsuite.But  I couldnt see my workflow action script in Debugger, even if I invoked the custom action.

I use Eclipse IDE and upload my file to Netsuite. Here is my code, simply it just adds expense report  info note to employee when the empolyee expense report is created.  It has a problem with returning type.

```
function UpdateEmployeeWithExpenseReport()
{
   var stFrequentCriteria = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT',
        'custscript_oradata_freq_trav_limit');  // get value of the script parameter
   var intFrequentCriteria = parseInt(stFrequentCriteria); //the limit of frequency
   var recExpenseReport = nlapiGetNewRecord();
   var stEntity = recExpenseReport.getFieldValue('entity');  
   var today = new Date();
   var aMonthAgo = nlapiAddDays(today, -30); 
   // filter just the main lines of expenses
   var arrSearchFilters =  [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('employee', null, 'is', stEntity),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('trandate', null, 'within', aMonthAgo, today),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T') ];                                                   
   var arrSearchColumns = [ new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', null, 'count') ]; // Note: count is not a field, it just counts internal id based on  Empolyee expenses reports
   var arrSearchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('expensereport', null,
        arrSearchFilters, arrSearchColumns);
   var stCount = arrSearchResults[0].getValue(arrSearchColumns[0]); //                                                                  
   var count = parseInt(stCount);
   var stFrequentTraveler = '';
   if (count >= intFrequentCriteria)
   {
      stFrequentTraveler = 'Frequent';
   }
   else 
   {
    stFrequentTraveler = 'Infrequent';
   }

   var stAmount = recExpenseReport.getFieldValue('amount');
   var intExpenseLines = recExpenseReport.getLineItemCount('expense');
   var stNotes = '';
   stNotes += stFrequentTraveler + 'Traveler' + '\n';
   stNotes += 'Last Expense Report' + '\n';
   stNotes += '--Expense Report Total= ' + stAmount + '\n';
   stNotes += '--Expense Lines = ' + intExpenseLines;

   var recEmployee = nlapiLoadRecord('employee', stEntity); // 1 internal name of record, 2.internal id for the  record

   recEmployee.setFieldValue('comments', stNotes);
   nlapiLogExecution('tDEBUG', 'stEntity', stEntity);
   stEntity = recEmployee.getFieldValue('entityid');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your script to show up in the Netsuite Script Debugger, you need to have the Status set to "Testing" on the Script Deployment Record.

Comment: Usually I set "Testing" to the Status of Script Deployment Record

Comment: I want to notify that, eventually i debugged my  script,  problem was with deployment, I couldnt deploy it as it has to be